# React Native app fails to start in production mode

Tags: android, react-native, expo, production

There is the text on Android emulator screen:

```
Property 'DOMRectReadOnly' doesn' exist
Property 'DOMRectReadOnly' doesn' exist

ReferenceError: Property 'DOMRectReadOnly' doesn't exist
  at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify =false&app=io.test&modulesOnly=false& runModule=true:31940:21)
  at loadModuleImplementation (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android &dev=true&minify=faise&app=io.test& modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:321:14)
  at guardedLoadModule (http://10.0.2.2:8081 /index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true& minify=false&app=io.test&modulesOnly= faise&runModule=true:218:38)
  at metroRequire (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index .bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify =false&app=io.test&modulesOnly=false& runModule=true:120:92)
  at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index .bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify =false&app=io.test&modulesOnly=false& 
(Min./PIA 11[...]
Button: DISMISS (ESC)
button: RELOAD (R, R)
```

As you see the `minify=false`, so the code which generates the error is:

```js
__d(function (global, _$$_REQUIRE, _$$_IMPORT_DEFAULT, _$$_IMPORT_ALL, module, exports, _dependencyMap) {
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
  });
  exports.default = void 0;
  class DOMRectReadOnly {
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
      // ..
    }
    // ..
    }
  }
  exports.default = DOMRectReadOnly;
                 // ^ line 31940:21
},102,[],"node_modules/react-native/Libraries/DOM/Geometry/DOMRectReadOnly.js");
```

So the `DOMRectReadOnly` is a class, not a property, I have no idea what is wrong.

Dependencies:

```json
{
    "@expo/cli": "0.6.2",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native": "0.72.2",
    "expo": "49.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4"
  }
```

The error is not present when the debugging is enabled. On my smartphone in Expo Go the error is the same.